# Using a copr repo that has packages for older versions of Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

I've enabled a copr repository with:

```
dnf copr enable jonludlam/opam
```

When I attempt to install `dnf -v -y install opam`, it's clear that I am searching for a dnf repo that doesn't exists:

```
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
Loaded plugins: playground, reposync, config-manager, download, builddep, noroot, debuginfo-install, Query, protected_packages, needs-restarting, generate_completion_cache, copr
DNF version: 1.1.10
repo: using cache for: rpmfusion-free
not found deltainfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free
not found updateinfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free
Cannot download 'https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/jonludlam/opam/fedora-25-x86_64/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried.
repo: using cache for: epel
not found deltainfo for: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64
repo: using cache for: updates
repo: using cache for: rpmfusion-free-updates
not found deltainfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free - Updates
not found updateinfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 25 - Free - Updates
repo: using cache for: fedora
not found updateinfo for: Fedora 25 - x86_64
Cannot download 'https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/sergiomb/google-drive-ocamlfuse/fedora-25-x86_64/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'jonludlam-opam', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'sergiomb-google-drive-ocamlfuse', disabling.
rpmfusion-free: using metadata from Fri Nov 18 18:41:21 2016.
epel: using metadata from Wed Nov 30 02:44:26 2016.
updates: using metadata from Tue Nov 29 23:47:49 2016.
rpmfusion-free-updates: using metadata from Mon Nov 28 03:10:31 2016.
fedora: using metadata from Thu Nov 17 05:09:01 2016.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:02:29 ago on Wed Nov 30 14:25:15 2016.
No package opam available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Given that I'm on Fedora 25, but the packages are only listed for up to Fedora 24 (https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/jonludlam/opam/), is it possible to enforce dnf to use any particular version?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COPR repo was not update for some time and therefore the pacakges were not built for your Fedora version. There are few possibilities to do:

- Ask the repo owner to rebuild the package for Fedora 25 (preferred)
- Modify the `/etc/yum.repos.d/_copr_jonludlam-opam.repo` and replace the `$releasever` with the `23`. This will install the latest packages built
- [Fork the project](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jonludlam/opam/) and rebuild the packages yourself for Fedora 25 (if you have FAS account)

Comment: Thank you!  For future reference to others, I traverse the repo in a web browser to locate the http location of the rpm, then used `dnf install http://.../..rpm` to install the latest available rpm.

Comment: Yes, this is the fourth possibility, but it does not guarantee you any future updates from the repo owner, which is pretty bad in case of some security issue in that application.